# Issues with validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a working validation on my user model. But since we're discovered that users tend to give up during their long registration form, we've split up registration form into steps so that user can give up any time and still use the site.

I'm having issues with the first step of user registration with validations. Here is the relevant bit of my User model :

```
with_options :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "get_started" } do |user|
    user.validates :firstname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    user.validates :surname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    user.validates :email, presence:   true,
              format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

    user.validates :password_digest, presence: true
    user.validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

This validation works perfectly. However we now added facebook so its possible to login with facebook and we have hidden fields in our form `facebook_uid`. So I want to validate password only if these fields are nil.

Here is how I tried to modify my current validation :

```
with_options :if => lambda { |u| u.current_step == "get_started" } do |user|
   user.validates :firstname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
   user.validates :surname, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
   user.validates :email, presence:   true,
        format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

   with_options :if => lambda { |u| u.facebook_uid.nil? } do |user|
     user.validates :password_digest, presence: true
   end

   with_options :if => lambda { |u| u.user.password_digest_changed? && !u.password.nil? } do |user|
    user.validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
   end
end
```

Or inline (the relevant password part only) :

```
user.validates :password_digest, presence: true, if: lambda { |u| u.facebook_uid.nil? }
user.validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, if: lambda { |u| u.user.password_digest_changed? && !u.password.nil? }
```

None of these worked for me, whatever I tried I get this error :

```
undefined method `user' for #<User:0x00000008e924a8>
```

Again if I remove ifs and lambdas works as charm. Is there another way of accomplishing this or something I'm currently doing wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `password` validation lambda, you're calling

```
u.user.password_digest_changed? && !u.password.nil?
```

ie, you're sending a `user` method to the `u` object, which is your `User` instance. That object doesn't respond to `user`. You probably just want

```
u.password_digest_changed? && !u.password.nil?
```

Comment: thanks Jacob. Stupid me, looking at it for some time now. Didn't see that one.